# Android DrawerLayout (with NavigationView) behind status bar

Tags: android, drawerlayout, navigationview, android-statusbar

I have an app with a `DrawerLayout` that contains a `NavigationView`:

**activity_layout.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/activity_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.exmaple.appname.activityname">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/actionbar_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"/>

        […]

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:menu="@menu/nav_drawer"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I have added the following styles as well:

**styles.xml:**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    […]

    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

**values-21/styles.xml:**

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

All of this code is based on the [Google I/O Schedule App](https://github.com/google/iosched), however the `DrawerLayout` still does not render behind the status bar. Any ideas as to why this combination of solutions isn't working and what solutions might? I've found that drawing behind the status bar is never a one-size-fits-all solution, but after trying every combination of solutions on Stack Overflow that I can think of, I still can't get it.

Current drawer image:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add `<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>` in `values-21/styles.xml` and remove this `<item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>`

add `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` to your `NavigationView` in xml

> Working example!

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
</style>
```

Result [image]

> Edited (main layout)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" <--This is mandatory 
    tools:context=".ui.activities.MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true" /><--This is mandatory 

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

> Current Result [image]
>
> Update: I lookup your style-v21 and found below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Please replace it with this

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Nope. I switched the `statusBarColor` for `windowTranslucentStatus` (in `v21`) with no luck. I then added `fistsSystemWindows` to the `NavigationView` (though I am not using a header and don't want it behind the status bar), and still nothing. The background colour of the `NavigationView` still only draws to the status bar. I will work on providing a full code sample soon.

Comment: (Correction above: I do want the `NavigationView` to be `fitsSystemWindow`, as that is the background I want to extend behind the status bar)

Comment: Updated with image in original question. I want what you have shown, but without the header image. The background colour of the drawer should extend behind the status bar.

Comment: Yeah, I tried the `fitsSystemWindows` on the `NavView` before and it didn't fix anything. I'll post that code sample when I get a chance.

Comment: Added a link to the demo repo. The demo app displays the exact same issue on my test device, running `7.1.1`.

Comment: Yes, the issue was how I was overriding the style. Thanks for the answer!