# Can't change StatusBar color using MaterialDrawer library

Tags: android, colors

I'm trying to change the `StatusBar` color programatically with no success. I'm using the [MaterialDrawer](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer) library to create the nav drawer btw.

Tried differents solutions I found in internet but no one worked, the statusbar always show the primaryDark

Tried programatically:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                Window window = getWindow();
                window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
                window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
                window.setStatusBarColor(Color.BLUE);
}
```

Also tried with themes:

```
if (dark) 
    setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_Dark_NoActionBar);
else 
    setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_NoActionBar);


<style name="AppTheme.Dark.NoActionBar" parent="MaterialDrawerTheme">
    <item name="android:colorPrimary" tools:targetApi="lollipop">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark" tools:targetApi="lollipop">#cfcfcf</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">#cfcfcf</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent" tools:targetApi="lollipop">@color/md_black_1000</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentTransitions" tools:targetApi="lollipop">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/MaterialDrawer.DrawerArrowStyle.Black</item>
    <item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/DatePickerDialogThemeDark</item>
    <item name="android:timePickerDialogTheme">@style/DatePickerDialogThemeDark</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:colorAccent" tools:targetApi="lollipop">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/DatePickerDialogThemeLight</item>
        <item name="android:timePickerDialogTheme">@style/DatePickerDialogThemeLight</item>
    </style>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="MaterialDrawerTheme.Light">
    <item name="android:colorPrimary" tools:targetApi="lollipop">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark" tools:targetApi="lollipop">@color/colorPrimaryDark
    </item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent" tools:targetApi="lollipop">@color/md_blue_300</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentTransitions" tools:targetApi="lollipop">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds" tools:targetApi="lollipop">true</item>
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/MaterialDrawer.DrawerArrowStyle</item>
</style>
```

And finally tried using this piece of code of MaterialDrawer library:

```
drawer.getDrawerLayout().setStatusBarBackgroundColor(color);
```

`drawer` is the result of `DrawerBuilder`. The app has 2 primary colors depending on some variables the user put in the login/register. This colors are blue and white. The app works nice, except for that the StatusBar only is tinted with primaryDark even if I use the codes I posted above. The only mode I can change the color is to modify the colorPrimary or putting this into colors:

```
<color name="materialize_primary_dark">@color/md_red_500</color>
```

But it changes the color as primaryDark do, and I have to change it to white for white mode and blue for blue mode.

Thanks.

Comment: remove thos part in first solution
"window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);" 
maybe it works!!

Comment: Tried, but the color doesn't change. I think is something from MaterialDrawer that overrides it, but i don't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As soon as you have a `DrawerLayout` in the root of your `View` which has the `fitsSystemWindows` flag, the StatusBar color will be managed by this views `"scrim"`.

So in your case you can do the following to adjust the `StatusBar`'s color dynamically:

```
public void setStatusBarColor(@ColorInt int color){
    drawer.getDrawerLayout().setStatusBarBackgroundColor(color);
}
```

Comment: Resolved the error rewritting again all the styles and the MainActivity. Didn't found finally the error but using this answer, after rewritting all, I can change the color finally.

Answer (score 1):

> You not need library for that use this style-v21

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
</style>
```

> Drawer layout

```
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true" /><--This is mandatory 

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

> Or you can refer my accepted answer here [Android DrawerLayout (with NavigationView) behind status bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41501857/android-drawerlayout-with-navigationview-behind-status-bar/41502238#41502238)

Comment: The issue isn't about the library. it's about the StatusBar. and this is handled by the DrawerLayout (which is also the base for the NavigationView)

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41501857/android-drawerlayout-with-navigationview-behind-status-bar/41502238#41502238